# Oracle text search default Stop words for non english locales

Tags: oracle, full-text-search, stop-words, text-search

Oracle documentation lists following default stop words. 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/astopsup.htm#CCREF1400

This includes stop words from all languages. But when i query my database to view list of stop words, it only shows English words. 
SELECT * FROM ctx_stopwords;

It doesn't list non english stop words. I may be missing something here. I am looking for a query which returns all the default oracle stop words in all languages. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for scripts in $ORACLE_HOME/ctx/admin/defaults/

```
drdefus.sql - american
drdefd.sql  - german
```

Comment: Thank you. I see all locale specific files in that location. If i want to use stop words from all locales, does that mean i have to manually install all those locales?

Comment: Yes, but you can write a simple script to run all scripts if a folder